# Rails3 Nested Attributes Using Parent Values in Save Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a simple nested form working in my rails3 application. I'm trying to work out how to save a value from the parent model into the child when saving.

```
class Radcheck < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'radcheck'
  attr_accessible :attribute_name, :username, :value, :op
  belongs_to :raduser  
end

class Raduser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :radcheck, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :radcheck  
end
```

And my form:

```
<%= form_for @raduser do |f| %>  
  <p>  
    <%= f.label :username %><br />  
    <%= f.text_field :username %>  
  </p>  
  <%= f.fields_for :radcheck do |builder| %>  
  <li>  
    <%= builder.label :attribute_name %><%= builder.text_field :attribute_name %>  

  </li>  
  <% end %>  
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>  
<% end %>
```

What I want to do is save the Raduser.username value in to the radcheck table on save. For each record.

I've tried putting something in the controller but that wasn't really working for us.

-- Update --

In my radcheck controller, I've tried this (as a test) but the values don't save.

```
def create
      @radcheck = Radcheck.new(params[:radcheck])
      @radcheck.username = '123'
      respond_to do |format|
        if @radcheck.save

          format.html { redirect_to @radcheck, notice: 'Radcheck was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @radcheck, status: :created, radcheck: @radcheck }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @radcheck.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

Have also tried in radusers but that gave error.

Comment: can you put controller code that you have tried?

Comment: @naren-sisodiya. Sure, just updated.

Comment: It seems that username is a column of radcheck table(looking at the model and controller code)..In your view code, it is treated like a column of radusers table

Comment: @rubyprince that's right - they both have that column - am working with a legacy db and can't update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the controller code you posted is for the Radcheck controller, correct? If so, the form you have also posted will be using the `create` action of the `RaduserController` class, not the one from `RadcheckController`. This would explain why you aren't seeing the username '123' in the radcheck rows.

If the username field is the same between parent and child, a common way to sync these two up would be with an observer or a `before_save` callback. I'll outline the `before_save` method below:

```
class Radcheck < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'radcheck'
  attr_accessible :attribute_name, :username, :value, :op
  belongs_to :raduser

  before_save :sync_usernames

private

  def sync_usernames
    self.username = self.raduser.username
  end
end
```

I've tested this with Rails 3.1 and it works; however, I know I have run into issues accessing parent models within a child model in previous versions of Rails. In those cases, I had to put the `before_save` action on the parent model, and have it iterate over each child, setting the appropriate attributes that way.

Comment: I'm on 3.1.1 - I get an insert in the log for raduser but it doesn't look like anything's going in to radcheck. J

Comment: Strangely, it now works. Bit concerned I didn't do much to get it going. Thanks for sorting :)

Comment: It does seem odd that it would initially not work, and then suddenly start working. Without knowing more about your setup, I can only make guesses as to why that happened. At any rate, glad to hear it's working for you now.

Comment: Not a big fan of intermittent issues either!! thanks again :)