# Rails3 Nested Attribute Validation and Control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm rolling with a legacy database unfortunately and am trying to build my rails3 app around it.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211205/rails3-nested-attributes-using-parent-values-in-save-action/8213297#8213297) previous post, I've figured out where I'm going but still think I'm approaching incorrectly.

My basic problem is that main my main data is stored in a table with multiple rows, each with a different attribute value:

```
+-----+----------+----------------+----+---------------+------------+
| id  | username | attribute_name | op | value         | raduser_id |
+-----+----------+----------------+----+---------------+------------+
| 173 | jenny    | User-Password  | := | March 25 2011 |         33 |
| 172 | jenny    | User-Password  | := | 1234          |         33 |
+-----+----------+----------------+----+---------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I was using a nested form to enter this information but it's not really doing what I need. I can add the nested attributes and set a field thanks to the previous question now.

The issue I have is that I need some more control over my user's inputs. For instance, I need to restrict them to three distinct attributes:

User-Password, Expiration, Simultaneous-Use

I also need to validate the fields. I can't do so with the nested form.

My plan was to get the user to enter these in the parent model and propagate down but I do not have a clue how to do this and save out to separate rows, like I do with my nested atributes.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

--UPDATE--

raduser.rb

```
class Raduser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :radcheck, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :radcheck, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:value].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true   

end
```

radcheck.rb

```
class Radcheck < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'radcheck'
  attr_accessible :attribute_name, :username, :value, :op, :groupname
  belongs_to :raduser

  has_many :radusergroup, :dependent => :destroy, :primary_key => :username, :foreign_key => :groupname
  has_many :radgroupcheck, :through => :radusergroup

  before_save :sync_usernames

  private

    def sync_usernames
      self.username = self.raduser.username
    end
end
```

Comment: I am not sure about your data model..can u give the fields in radusers table also and how the entities raduser and radcheck are related?

Comment: @rubyprince Sorry, don't know why I didn't see your comment before. Will do so now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try placing the validations in the `radcheck.rb` model? Try this code:

radcheck.rb

```
class Radcheck < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'radcheck'
  attr_accessible :attribute_name, :username, :value, :op, :groupname
  belongs_to :raduser

  validates :attribute_name, :inclusion => { :in => %w(User-Password Expiration Simultaneous-Use) }

  before_save :sync_usernames

  private

  def sync_usernames
    self.username = self.raduser.username
  end
end
```

raduser.rb

```
class Raduser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :radcheck, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :radcheck, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:value].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true   

end
```

radusers_controller.rb

```
def new
  @raduser = Raduser.new
  @raduser.radcheck.build
end

def create
  @raduser = Raduser.new(params[:raduser])
  if @raduser.save
    redirect_to(@raduser, :notice => 'Raduser was successfully created.')
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

and finally the form

```
<% if @raduser.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@raduser.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this raduser from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @raduser.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @raduser do |f| %>  
  <p>  
    <%= f.label :username %><br />  
    <%= f.text_field :username %>  
  </p>  
  <%= f.fields_for :radcheck do |builder| %>  
    <li>  
      <%= builder.label :attribute_name %>
      <%= builder.text_field :attribute_name %>  
    </li>  
  <% end %>  
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>  
<% end %>
```

When I tried to save with attribute name other than User-Password, Expiration, Simultaneous-Use, it is giving

```
1 error prohibited this raduser from being saved:

 - Attribute name is not included in the list
```

If you want to change the message, you can add `:message` to the validations. You can add other validations like this in the `Radcheck` model.

See these links [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast), [Complex form codes](https://github.com/alloy/complex-form-examples)

Comment: What about if I need to validate the actual content of the fields, like checking for a date?

Comment: @rubyprice - am trying to validate the fields but it simply doesn't work. Have followed your instructions to the letter and been through the tutorials online. Any suggestions how I can validate the attribute_name field?